# Associating HTTP request and response

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking for feedback on how to associate HTTP requests and responses. This was brought up by a consumer of my REST API (built using ASP.NET Web API). I could probably allow the client to send a header value (e.g., Request-Identifier) in the request and then just return it as a header value in the response. I'm not aware of any built-in support for this, or even an existing HTTP header type to be used for this. Any suggestions or feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft did something similar with Sharepoint in that they provided what they call 'Correlation IDs'.  On [this](http://blog.michelbarneveld.nl/michel/archive/2009/11/08/x-sharepointhealthscore-a-new-sharepoint-2010-http-header.aspx) link, you'll see how it gets passed into and out of the server.  They go one step farther and log all this information on the system for easy viewing / searching.  You might consider something similar.  It just seems like a matter of setting the naming scheme and then always remembering to put the values in on both the request and the response.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of SharePoint's correlation id, but I believe they are leveraging the fact that they control the request and response. I wasn't clear about the point of only being a REST API. I will maintain (and return) a correlation id for logging on my end, but I wasn't sure about letting the client request include a request identifier. I guess I could limit the length of it if passed in as a header.